# Loop through nodes inserting elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, nodes, tampermonkey

I am quite new to Javascript, making a TamperMonkey script that edits a website's sale values to include some otherwise hidden costs.

I wish to add a `span` element within any elements of the class `awe-rt-CurrentPrice` showing this corrected costs (the value will be calculated based on a value found elsewhere in the same element).

Example Input (part of the webpage)

```html
<p class="awe-rt-HideOnEnd galleryData--values">
    <span class="awe-rt-CurrentPrice galleryPrice">
        £
        <span class="NumberPart" style="display: inline-block;">75.00</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

Desired output (with an extra span added)

```html
<p class="awe-rt-HideOnEnd galleryData--values">
    <span class="awe-rt-CurrentPrice galleryPrice">
        £
        <span class="NumberPart" style="display: inline-block;">75.00</span>
        <span> (£108)</span>
    </span>
</p>
```

My attempt at Tampermonkey script so far:

```js
MainAction()
function MainAction() {
    'use strict';
    var priceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.awe-rt-CurrentPrice')
    alert("Elements identified:" + priceElements.length)
    priceElements.forEach(PerValInsert())
    alert("process complete; costs corrected")
};
function PerValInsert(CurrentNode, i) {
    // for a price element, insert the corrected price next to it
    var JPElement = CurrentNode.querySelector('NumberPart')
    var CorrectValue = JPElement.value * 1.44 // add 44% hidden costs to value
    var CorrectValNode = document.createtextnode("<span> (£" + CorrectValue + ")</span>")
    CurrentNode.appendChild(CorrectValNode)
    console.log("Element " + i + "corrected")
};
```

I believe the error is either with the `priceElements.forEach()` line or the `CurrentNode.querySelector` line in the second function.

I've googled various things on the theme of 'finding elements within a node' and 'node properties in javascript' but haven't been able to identify the issue. The error I'm getting in the console is

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'querySelector')
>
> at PerValInsert
>
> at MainAction

Comment: `priceElements.forEach(PerValInsert())` should be `priceElements.forEach(PerValInsert)` because the `()` means that you want to *call* the function and pass its return value.

Comment: `CurrentNode.querySelector('NumberPart')` is `CurrentNode.querySelector('.NumberPart')` and `createtextnode` is `createTextNode`

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, common JavaScript coding style uses camel-case names for functions and variables, names that start with lower-case letters except for constructor functions (classes).